# Streaming audio from player to network's devices on Mac

Tags: macos, mac

How to instantly send audio from iTunes (or other Mac player) to wi-fi router and make it available to other network's devices by using ip:port?

Is it way to make it with video?

Comment: Is hardware purchases out of the question?  An Airport Express or Apple TV would work easily...

Answer (score 2):

iTunes can stream audio to any AirPort Express, Apple TV, or third party AirPlay-compatible speakers. It can also stream video to Apple TV.

For streaming audio from other apps, see Rogue Amoeba's "Airfoil" product line.